# Can I see the unsuccessfully pushed files on SVN/GIT repository?

Tags: git, svn, repository, tortoisesvn, tortoisegit

I have been working on code (want to know for both SVN and Git too), and last Push to remote repo, has been unsuccessful because of conflicts (my local repo was not update). Then accidentally, project (with updated codes) has been deleted from PC (couldn't recover it).

Is there any chance that I might see that file (codes) on remote repo, so I can recover my changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not an expert on SVN internals, so when we get to the long answer I can only speak for Git here, but the short answer is no, you cannot get unpushed files from the server.

For Git, the long answer is: *maybe, but probably not, and to find out, you will need to have direct login access to the server, so that you can poke around in the repository internals.*  The fundamental issues here are:

- Git doesn't push *files* at all.  Git pushes *commits*.  The commit has either made it to the server, or not.
- Once the commit arrives at the server, it is up to the server to decide whether to *accept or reject* the commit, but the details here matter quite a bit.  You said:

  > last Push to remote repo, has been unsuccessful

  What does "has been unsuccessful" *mean?*  Obviously the push failed, but *how* did it fail?  Was the connection never established?  Was the connection established, then broken before the transfers of all commits succeeded?  Or, did the transfers of commits all succeed, but then the server announced to you that, for some reason, it disliked your commits and refused to incorporate them?

If your commits did arrive on the server intact, but the server refused to accept them, we then need to know even more details about the server:  What version of Git is installed?  How is it (Git in general, and this repository in particular) configured?  How long ago was the failure and has a garbage-collection pass run yet?

In general, the design of *any* commit-based system is this: **A commit is atomic.  It either succeeds, in which case *all* files are updated / all data are stored, or it fails, in which case *no* files are updated  / no data are stored.**  Whether and when it is possible to retrieve something that was deliberately *not* stored (but may have been put into a temporary area, such as a transaction log) falls outside the design parameters.

For most practical purposes, the answer remains no: commits that were not added to the repository are simply not there to be obtained.

Comment: thanks for excellent answer... btw, `...has been unsuccessful because of conflicts (my local repo was not update)..`

Comment: Those are not conflicts (which implies *merge conflicts*, which occur only during merging, not during pushing which does no merging). If you got a rejection due to a `non-fast-forward` error, the commits *may* be on the server, if they have not been garbage collected and the server is using an old version of Git (and hence not using the new quarantine-area technique).